# Laravel DB Query count always NULL Value Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use this Code to Count my `referrals`. i have 3 Users where has an Value (ID) in `referer_id`  and one User with `NULL`. But why i get as Result always `1` and not `3` ?? It workes always for me, i dont know whats the Problem or why Count this Query the row with `NULL`?

```
<?php $count = DB::table('referral_user')->where('referer_id')->count(); echo $count; ?>
```

Anyone an Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`whereNotNull()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) method:

```
DB::table('referral_user')->whereNotNull('referer_id')->count()
```